# Card trick Java

Tags: java

I have been working on this program for over 30 hours and I am almost as lost now as when i first started. I've finally been able to print out 7 rows of 3 cards but i still have a few issues with my program.

1. I need to have the cards line up on the word "of"
2. when i call my PrintDeck() function it is supposed to print out all the cards in the deck but it does not.
3. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pick up the columns of cards in order to do the trick, If teh user chooses column 1 i'm supposed to pick it up second and then deal them out again in 7 rows of 3 columns. Then ask them to pick their card 2 more time and do the same thing.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated. I know some of the code is not very pretty but it has to be that way for the assignment in order for me to get credit :/ Thank you so much for all your help.

instructions: here is a doc if the link works ----> [instructions doc](http://word.office.live.com/wv/WordView.aspx?FBsrc=https://www.facebook.com/attachments/doc_preview.php?mid=id.376414855713455&id=05ba139ea8f82045adb02272e74d6bf2&metadata&access_token=1850923532%3aAQBxvI0QdjuXTt48&title=Cardtrick%20Instructions%20-%20Java)
Program Requirements:

Your program must generate its own random deck of cards using the following technique:

- generate a random integer for each card
- display a string value for each card ("Ace of Diamonds")
- use the rand() function to generate integer card values
- use the srand(time(0)) command (only once at the beginning of the program) to generate a truly random deck once the program has been tested and runs properly.

Each value must be converted to the format  of  as done in the example above. Whenever your program displays the cards they must line up as they do above, on the word "of".
Your program must deal the cards out by row and pick them up by column (3 times to make it work properly).
Your program must ask the player is he/she wants to printout the entire deck before playing. Each card must be printed out formatted as above.
Your program must ask the player if he/she wants to play again, and continue playing as many times as the player wants.
The program must ask the player for his/her name and refer to the player by name throughout the playing of the game.
Your program code must be logically organized using functions. You also must use the starter file provided. You will GET A ZERO (0) if you do not use the starter file!

The starter file provided: CardtrickStarterFile.java if this pastes weird here is a pastebin link:  http://pastebin.com/rsZY2vKq

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Random;

public class CardTrickStarterFile {
 private static Random rand = new Random();
 private static String PlayAgain;


public static void main(String[] args) { 

/* declare and initialize variables */
int column = 0, i = 0;

/* Declare a 52 element array of integers to be used as the deck of cards */
int[] deck = new int[52];

/* Declare a 7 by 3 array to receive the cards dealt to play the trick */
int[][] play = new int[7][3];

/* Declare a Scanner object for input */
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

/* Generate a random seed for the random number generator. */



/* Openning message.  Ask the player for his/her name */
System.out.println("\nHello, I am a computer program that is so smart");
System.out.println("I can even perform a card trick.  Here's how.\n");
System.out.println("To begin the card trick type in your name: ");
 String name = input.nextLine();

 char firstL = name.charAt(0);
    firstL = Character.toUpperCase(firstL);

name = replaceCharAt(name, 0, firstL);         
  /* Capitalize the first letter of the person's name. */


System.out.println("\nThank you " + name);

do
{
/* Build the deck */
BuildDeck(deck);

/* Ask if the player wants to see the entire deck. If so, print it out. */
System.out.println("Ok " + name + ", first things first.  Do you want to see what ");
System.out.println("the deck of cards looks like (y/n)? ");
String SeeDeck = input.nextLine();

switch (SeeDeck)
{
    case "y":
        PrintDeck(deck);
    break;
    case "n":
        System.out.println("Ok then let us begin.");
        Deal(deck,play);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}




System.out.printf("\n%s, pick a card and remember it...\n", name);

/* Begin the card trick loop */
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
/* Begin the trick by calling the function to deal out the first 21 cards */




/* Include error checking for entering which column */
    do
{
    /* Ask the player to pick a card and identify the column where the card is     */
    System.out.print("\nWhich column is your card in (0, 1, or 2)?: ");
    column = input.nextInt();
} while(column < 0 || column > 2);

/* Pick up the cards, by column, with the selected column second */



}

/* Display the top ten cards, then reveal the secret card */




/* if the player wants to play again */
System.out.printf("%s, would you like to play again (y/n)? ", name);
String PlayAgain = input.nextLine(); 

} 
while(PlayAgain == "y");

/* Exiting message */
System.out.println("\nThank you for playing the card trick!\n");
return;
}

public static String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, char c) {
return s.substring(0,pos) + c + s.substring(pos+1);
}

public static void BuildDeck( int deck[])
{
int[] used = new int[52];
int i = 0;
int card = 0;

/* Generate cards until the deck is full of integers */
while(i < deck.length)
{
    /* generate a random number between 0 and 51 */

    card = rand.nextInt(52);
    /* Check the used array at the position of the card.  
       If 0, add the card and set the used location to 1.  If 1, generate     another number */
    if(used[card] == 0)
    {
                used[card] = 1;
                deck[i] = card;
                i++;                

    }
}

}

public static void PrintDeck( int deck[] )
{

    for (int i=0; i < 52; i++){
        PrintCard(i);
    }

/* Print out each card in the deck */

}

public static void Deal( int deck[], int play[][] )
{
int card = 0;

/* deal cards by passing addresses of cardvalues from
   the deck array to the play array                   */
System.out.println("\n   Column 0           Column 1           Column 2");
System.out.println("=======================================================");        

    for(int row = 0; row < play.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < play[row].length; col++){               
            play[row][col]=deck[card];
           card++;
           System.out.printf("%s", PrintCard(play[row][col]) + "       ");
        } 

        System.out.println();
    }

}

 public static String PrintCard( int card )
 {
   int rank = (card % 13);
   int suit = (card / 13);
   String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades" }; 
   String[] ranks = { "King", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
     "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen"}; 

 return (ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit]); 

}

public static void PickUp( int deck[], int play[][], int column )
{
 int card = 0, row = 0;








return;
}

public static void SecretCard( int deck[] )
{
int card = 0;

System.out.println("\nFinding secret card...");
for(card = 0; card < 10; card++)
    PrintCard(deck[card]);

System.out.println("\nYour secret card is: ");
    PrintCard(deck[card]);
return;
}
}
```

Comment: did you copy and paste your code? I just ran it and got a bunch of errors.

Comment: Yes but It was weird pasting into the box, here is a pastebin link sorry if i did it wrong. Also the main error it should pull up has to do with a while loop but I can't build those things until i finish the PickUp() and other functions that the program uses :/ http://pastebin.com/8qSTbag6

Comment: The code will not compile without me debugging it. If you get it to the point where it compiles successfully, repost and I will try to help with your specific issue.

Comment: if you delete the for loops in the PickUp() it compiles i believe

Comment: @Brett: I'm gathering based on your description of the problem that this is a homework assignment. As such, I've added the homework tag for you - please do this yourself for future homework questions. This *can* be important - although it's great if you get an answer that helps you out, it's even more important that you get an answer you can *learn* from, and without the [tag:homework] tag you tend to get more of the former than the latter. Cheers!

Comment: Here you go, i don;t know how to get it to work in the main post but while i try to figure that out here is the pastebin  thank you for the help.http://pastebin.com/rsZY2vKq

Comment: Couple of questions, Is this your homework? Do you have to use arrays? Does the deck need to be shuffled?

Comment: This is a project so yes homework, it's due at midnight and its 8:40pm where i am, i've been working on it for a few days but recently i've put 30 hours straight no sleep and honestly just do not understand what to do at this point. I didn't realize there was a hwk tag i will use that from now on sorry for the confusion. Yes we have to use arrays and the if by shuffled you mean it has to put out random cards every time it deals or in a random order then yes. Hope that covers everything.

Comment: Can you create a `Card` object, or do you need to use numbers?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is it telling you your errors? You can't use strings in switch statements. You can use enums though

Comment: We have to use numbers, i wish i could make an object to me it seems it would make it easier but he said we had to do it the way he described in the comments of the code. It's an online class and I have literally email this professor like 5 times in the past week with no response at all :/

Comment: i'm using NetBeans IDE 7.1 if that helps, no errors when i compile the updated code i put up, but there are some parts of the program that are not even called or are not written yet due to me not understanding how to use them. I will look up enums now, i assume you  are referring to the SeeDeck string.

Comment: @BrettL., Yes, I am. I've never used NetBeans and I'm not too experienced with Java or Eclipse (IDE I'm using), but I'll try to help. If you type "@" and then a persons username, it will notify them that you responded to their post. It's easier to communicate like that.

Comment: @BrettL., Did he specifically say to use a switch statement? Are all the requirements in the comments, or is there more?

Comment: @Walkerneo  thank you very much for the help, I have Eclipse as well but it seems more difficult to navigate around than netbeans.

Comment: @BrettL., Alright. It looks like he gave you a shell of a working programming that he wanted you to fill out with the missing pieces. If that's true, can we see what he gave you for reference?

Comment: @Walkerneo i will paste the instructions into the main post in a moment, they are really not clear cause he tells us to use srand() and some other functions that others have told me are not even in java.

Comment: @Walkerneo http://pastebin.com/tQ8h0nnc

Comment: @BrettL., Can you put the instructions into a pastebin as well, it's confusing reading them up there.

Comment: @Walkerneo they don't paste properly for some reason, does this help?  http://www.scribd.com/doc/87117624/Cardtrick-Instructions-Java

Comment: @BrettL., Yeah, that's perfect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9438/discussion-between-brett-l-and-walkerneo)

Comment: @BrettL., Sorry, I don't think there's anything I can do to help. You could check out http://thenewboston.org/tutorials.php, though.

Comment: @dann.dev   chat doesn't load any messages for me, can we continue here please, i only have less than an hour left to finish this assignment :'(

Answer (score 2):

OK, there's a few things wrong, so i'll try help you bit by bit. The first is your print deck method, it doesn't actually print anything... you are also passing the wrong thing to it. have another look at ONLY this method and see if you can firstly make it print something, then secondly see why it's print the wrong things

Comment: I tried to build it by itself in another class but i needed to build printcard as well, and then declare a value for deck, that makes it print out 52 unique cards, is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: You can still use what you've got, I'm just not going to give you the answer.... But if you look at how you call your printdeck method, there are no println commands anywhere... figure out where to put that, one problem at a time is the best way to approach it if you are new

Comment: Only time we are supposed to call PD is when we give the option to let the user see all of the cards, therefore i put it in the switch statement following that question. I don't know how to get it to use the values from BuildDeck(deck); though and that's where my head starts to hurt. When i call BuildDeck does it create 52 randomly generated unique numbers? I think it does so when i call PrintDeck(deck) after calling BuildDeck shouldn't it use those numbers? Im sorry if i sound weird im really worn out from no sleep and it's becoming increasingly  difficult for me to grasp concepts.

Comment: When you call build deck, it puts random numbers into `deck`, and it is now available to be used. When you call `Printdeck` you pass `deck` to it. So now `PrintDeck` is running. That cycles through each card in `deck` and gives you a string of what it looks like. Somewhere along this process you need to print the string to the console using `System.out.println()`. See if you can just get that working

Comment: Am i not supposed to use PrintCard() then? Should i code print card's strings and stuff into the print deck?

Comment: I added this -------------------------------------------------------------------------for (int i=0; i < 52; i++){-----------------------------------------System.out.println(PrintCard(i));

Comment: sorry it looks so bad i can't figure out how to paste code using '' doesn't seem to work  for me :/

Comment: Does that print the deck out for you?

Comment: Would you happen to know how I should go about getting my "of"'s to line up when i call Deal() cause i get it to print out random cards in my rows and columns but i just don't know how to go about getting them  printed by centering the "of"'s thank you for helping me with this, i can't tell you what it means to have somebody else just look at this with me right now, i fell like im going crazy since i've been doing this for so long.

Comment: Ok, we're going to skip formatting etc, get the right answer first, then make it look pretty. You'll probably notice that it gives you the deck in order, not shuffled, look at what you are passing to `PrintCard` and think about what it actually is

Comment: Hmm, I'm just passing int 1-52 with the for loop then and not the numbers from the deck?

Comment: Yup, so change it to `deck[i]` then this passes the number from the deck at that position. Where are we upto now?

Comment: Wow, didn't realize that. Ok now we have a list of random cards sent from the deck function printed in a straight line an i need to format them?

Comment: Forget formatting to the end, easier to get everything running first. Look at your switch statement, it deal's the card when  they don't see the deck, but doesn't when they ask too, do you need to ask if they want to see the deck more then once?

Comment: Well if they say yes im supposed to show them the entire deck, if they say no i'm supposed to show then just eh 21 cards that may up the 3x7 table.

Comment: but if they say yes,, you show the deck and then ask for them to pick a card, never showing them the 3x7table

Comment: Sorry i think SO went down, yes your right so i need to call deal regardless after they see the deck

Comment: added: System.out.println("Now that you have seen the deck let us begin.");
            Deal(deck,play);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9440/discussion-between-dann-dev-and-brett-l)

Comment: I can make another switch to ask if they are satisfied as well but now im running into the problem that i don't know how to build the PickUp() function and am basically stuck from this point :(

Comment: i can't seem to get chat to work, it doesnt display my messages.      
    PickUp() function needs to be called after they make their choice as to which column their card is in.

Comment: chat doesn't load any messages for me, can we continue here please, i only have less than an hour left to finish this assignment :'(

Comment: Chat seems fine for me, that's weird. Depends on if you want to ask them again, the other thing you can do is just deal afterwards anyone. I'm not 100% on the pick up function, but I think you should get it working with out worrying about choosing anything yet. Try adding them to a new array, using for loops, but column first, then rows. HINT: it's the reverse of how they are currently printed out